# A bounded sequence with a diverting subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, education

Is there a bounded sequence with a divergent subsequence?

My thinking is that if we take a bounded sequence then Bolzano-Weierstraß tells us there exists a subsequence that converges in the set of Reals.

However, it doesn't necessarily mean that if it has a divergent subsequence then the original sequence was unbounded. Does it? A bit confused.

Comment: $0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots$ is bounded and divergent.

Comment: It's talking about a diverging sub-sequence.

Comment: The sequence itself is a subsequence.

Comment: Omit whatever terms you like, so long as you keep infinitely many $0$'s and infinitely many $1$'s.  (You don't have to omit any terms though, as @zw points out.)